# How to save .nb.html notebook file in another directory than the one with the .rmd file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, rnotebook

**Context:** I have a R project with disctinct folders for scripts, outputs and data. To match this logic, I would like to have `.rmd` files in the `./scripts/` folder while saving the `.nb.html` file in the `./outputs/` folder.

**Question:** how to make knit save the `.nd.html` file in the folder `./output/` when clicking the "Save" button in RStudio IDE?

I tried to change knitr options using [`knitr::opts_knit$set()`](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#package-options) without success. I know it is possible to use `rmarkdown::render(input = "./scripts/test.Rmd", output_dir = "./outputs/")` in a separate R script to do this but I am looking for a solution that does not require to make such separate R script.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71795416/10264278) is very close, and works for HTML outputs. However, with Notebooks it seems not to take into account the custom knit function into the YAML.

Here is the current folder-files tree:

```
C:.
|   testR.Rproj
|   
+---outputs
\---scripts
        test.Rmd
```

If I render the `test.Rmd`, I get the following:

```
C:.
|   testR.Rproj
|   
+---outputs
\---scripts
        test.nb.html
        test.Rmd
```

And the expected output is:

```
C:.
|   testR.Rproj
|   
+---outputs
|       test.nb.html
|       
\---scripts
        test.Rmd
```

Code to reproduce this structure **the .Rmd file is empty, I do not know how to make the exact same output as File > New File > R Notebook**:

```r
library(usethis)
library(rmarkdown)
# set up the folder and files
usethis::create_project(path = paste0(getwd(),"/testR"), open = FALSE, rstudio = TRUE)
dir.create(paste0(getwd(),"/testR/outputs"))
dir.create(paste0(getwd(),"/testR/scripts"))
file.edit(paste0(getwd(),"/testR/scripts/test.Rmd"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, in the yaml header, you can pass a function to `knit` parameter:

```
---
title: "Some Report"
knit: (function(input, ...) {rmarkdown::render(input, output_file="path/to/output/location/filename.html")})
output: html_document
---
```

You can read more [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-knit.html). Note although, in the link it is mentioned you can pass a multiline function, but I have had trouble with passing multiline function. Passing the function as a single line works. Since you are passing a function, you can parametrize (do more things) it further, for example see [here](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Rmarkdown-custom-knit-hook-to-compile-a-multi-part-document)

Comment: What a nice trick! It works very well with `.html` documents but it seems that `html_notebooks` are not supported. However, by using the `code_folding` YAML parameter with `html_document` instead of `html_notebook` it is possible to get very close to the expected output!

Comment: This YALM works: `knit: (function(input, ...) {rmarkdown::render(input, output_dir=paste0(rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file(), "/outputs/"))})
output: 
  html_document: 
    code_folding: hide`

Comment: This one does not: `knit: (function(input, ...) {rmarkdown::render(input, output_dir=paste0(rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file(), "/outputs/"))})
output: 
  html_notebook`