# R markdown / knitr: customize output directory

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, output-directory

I am new to Stackoverflow - so please excuse any possible strangeness in my post.

I have a simmilar question as [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13007156/tom), posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795416/how-can-i-adjust-the-output-folder-when-using-the-knitr-button-in-rmarkdown).

I want to save a pdf created by markdown in a specific directory. After several unsuccessful attempts (including a frustrating chat with GPT), I followed [starjas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12647315/starja) instructions in the post mentioned, yet unsuccessfully.

Here's my YAML header:

```
---
title: 'MyTitle'
subtitle: 'Analysis XYZ'
author: "Boris et al."
date: "2023-01-22"
knit: (function(input, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(input,
                    encoding = "UTF-8",
                    output_dir = "05-Reports")})
output: pdf_document
---
```

… and here some code snippets from the scripts main body:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = TRUE)
source("02-Scripts/03-LogMod-6-plot.R", local = knitr::knit_global())
```

`{r model results} model6.res.table <- simple_kable <- knitr::kable(model6.res, format = "pipe") model6.res.table`

Here's the error message I get:

> Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
> cannot open the connection
> Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> source -> file
> Execution halted

I believe that the problem has to do something with R not being able to find the output-directory specified (05-Reports). But I have no clue why, as this output-directory is within the working directory:

> getwd()
> [1] "/Users/my-User/Documents/studyXYZ/1-XYZdata/6-R/studyXYZ-R-Project"

> list.files()
> [1] "01-Data"               "02-Scripts"            "03-Outputs"          
> [4] "04-Plots"              "05-Reports"            "studyXYZ-R-Project.Rproj"

Maybe important to know: I am working with a R-project. Furthermore, in the Global Options under R Markdown, I set "Evaluate chunks in directory:" "Project", as [Julius Diel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7828161/julius-diel) mentioned in a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994958/error-cannot-open-the-connection-in-executing-knit-html-in-rstudio) regarding a similar topic:

"Error "cannot open the connection" in executing "knit HTML" in RStudio"
 
Before setting R's Global Options like this, I had other issues regarding the scource()-command from my markdown-script adressing the R-scripts containing the analysis-commands. Now the scourcing works fine and I get the results as expected when conducting the markdown script without specifying the output directory (in html and pdf). It's just that the pdf won't be saved where I want it.
 
Does anyone have a clue what causes this problem?

Comment: What are you attempting in rmarkdown::render() with the encoding argument? The encoding is always assumed to be UTF-8. Have you attempted the markdown with the default: encoding = "UTF-8"?

Comment: I followed starjas instructions without giving this argument a second thought. I should have realized that the placeholder needs to be substituted.

I did that now (and edited my first post). The problem persists.

Moreover, I tried an other solution: I called the .Rmd file from a regular R script:

```rmarkdown::render(input = "Folder/Script.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document", output_file   = "Report.pdf", output_dir = "05-Reports")```

This results in nearly the same error message:

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection

Comment: Update: I found a workaround: In the part where I source the regular R script, I explicitly set the wd and added the absolute path to the source:

```setwd("/Users/my-User/Documents/studyXYZ/1-XYZdata/6-R/studyXYZ-R-Project")```

```source("/Users/my-User/Documents/studyXYZ/1-XYZdata/6-R/studyXYZ-R-Project/02-Scripts/03-LogMod-6-plot.R")```

And voilà - the pdf finally is stored in the desired output directory ("05-Reports").

However, I think that there are problems of redundancy in this solution. Furthermore, I want to avoid absolute paths for interchangeability reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know about the option `Evaluate chunks in directory: "Project"`. Previously, I used the following in the setup chunk:

```
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())
```

However, this option is ignored (as well as the option set in RStudio) when using `rmarkdown::render` in the header of the document. You need to set `knit_root_dir` to define the root directory from which you the can specify relative paths in `source` used in your rmarkdown document:

```
knit: (function(input, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(input,
                    output_dir = "05-Reports",
                    knit_root_dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())})
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you very much, starja! You saved me additional hours of frustrating attempts to solve my problem.

Awkward that R in this regard ignores both a setting from global options as well as an option set by code but will only comply with this specific argument...